# Why is onDraw not working when I call invalidate() within the onTouchEvent() method?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview, invalidation

My friend and I are working an a piece of a larger Android project.   What this piece needs to do is allow us to implement hand drawing on a touch screen using a bitmap and a surface view. To be clear, what we ultimately want is when the user instantiates a touch event, that the proper pixels change color so that if the user, for example, writes their name on the touch screen, their name appears in their own handwriting. I believe the problem lies within the invalidate method, which is called when the screen is touched. Using log output we found that the onDraw method is not called/used. The reason we are using bitmaps is because they can be compressed and sent over a network. If there is a better way to implement the functionality then we would be open to suggestions.

```
`/**
 * 
 */
package com.example.practice_app;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Color;

//Debugging packages
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.RuntimeException;

/**
 * @author Asus
 *
 */
public class WhiteBoardView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    //Class fields:
    //SurfaceHolder:
    SurfaceHolder holder;

    //Current context:
    Context currentContext;

    //Graphics:
    private DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    //private Bitmap ourBitmap;
    private Bitmap ourBitmap;
    private Canvas ourCanvas;
    private Paint paint;
    private View myView;




    //Class Methods:
    /**
     * @param context
     */

    public WhiteBoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        final String CONSTRU_TAG = "Constructor";

        //Initialize class fields;
        currentContext = context;
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);

        //Create the Canvas and the Bitmap:
         metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager)getWindowManager()).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        try{ourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);}
        catch(IllegalArgumentException argEr){
            Log.e("BITMAP_CREATE","Error creating the bitmap: IllegalArgumentException");
        }


        ourCanvas = new Canvas(ourBitmap);
        if(ourBitmap == null)
        {
            Log.e(CONSTRU_TAG, "ourBitmap is \"null\".");
        }
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


    }

    private Object getWindowManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return currentContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public WhiteBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        final String CONSTRUC_TAG2 = "Constructor(Context, AttributeSet)";
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        //Initialize class fields;
        currentContext = context;
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);

        //Create the Canvas and the Bitmap:
         metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager)getWindowManager()).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        try{ourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);}
        catch(IllegalArgumentException argEr){
            Log.e("BITMAP_CREATE","Error creating the bitmap: IllegalArgumentException");
        }


        ourCanvas = new Canvas(ourBitmap);
        if(ourBitmap == null)
        {
            Log.e(CONSTRUC_TAG2, "ourBitmap is \"null\".");
        }
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public WhiteBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        final String CONSTRUC_TAG3 = "Constructr(Context, AttributeSet, int)";
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        //Initialize class fields;
        currentContext = context;
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);

        //Create the Canvas and the Bitmap:
         metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager)getWindowManager()).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        try{ourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);}
        catch(IllegalArgumentException argEr){
            Log.e("BITMAP_CREATE","Error creating the bitmap: IllegalArgumentException");
        }


        ourCanvas = new Canvas(ourBitmap);
        if(ourBitmap == null)
        {
            Log.e(CONSTRUC_TAG3, "ourBitmap is \"null\".");
        }
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    //Event Handlers:
    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        //Declare local variables:
        final String ONTOUCH_TAG = "onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)";
        boolean eventHandled = true;
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch(e.getAction())
        {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //Log.i(ONTOUCH_TAG, "Hurray! Touch is working!");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(((x >= 0) && (x <= ourBitmap.getWidth())) && ((y >= 0) && (y <= ourBitmap.getHeight())))
            {  

               ourBitmap.setPixel((int)x, (int)y, paint.getColor());

                   invalidate();

            }

            break;

    }
        return eventHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(ourBitmap, null, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}'

And here is the Activity that WhiteBoardView is associated with.

package com.example.practice_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Whiteboard extends Activity {

    //Class fields:
    Bitmap ourBitmap;
    Canvas ourCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Call the superclass constructor:
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get the current Device's measurements:
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        //Create the Bitmap and Canvas objects
        ourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        ourCanvas = new Canvas(ourBitmap);

        //Set the UI layout for this activity:
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_whiteboard);

    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.whiteboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're drawing on a SurfaceView you need to use the `surfaceCreated / Updated / Destroyed` methods and do the drawing onto the `Surface` in the `SurfaceHolder`.

If you change your class to extend `View` and implement `onMeasure` it should work.